# How to track messages from Facebook API

Tags: facebook-graph-api, message, user-tracking

I´m trying to track messages sent to my Facebook friends.

For example: I sent a message to James Bond, how do I know if he read it or not?

Answer (score 0):

The Facebook Graph API does not support this yet - http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/message/. I suspect this is because there is no guaranteed way to see if a message has been read or not based on how the user accesses their messages.

It would also require permission tokens to be passed in a three-legged (recipient to application, recipient to sender) verification.